# Cannot debug Windows Phone app after install Visual Studio 2014 CTP

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've have a strange error with Windows Phone Emulator.
Last time I used Visual Studio 2013 and everything worked fine.

**Recently I try Visual Studio 2014 CTP parallel with VS2013 but now I cannot debug Windows Phone app with Emulator from VS2013**.

The app deploy successful and I can run it from Emulator but when I hit F5 VS always show:

**"The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."**

I've removed all Visual Studio 2014 CTP and Emulator 14 but it's not effect.

Could anyone here have similar error?
Please show me what problems is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still debugging with WP7 Emulator by ordering: Deploy app then Debug but WP8 Emulator not work for debugging anymore

Comment: I had a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432007/upgrading-wp8-to-wp8-1-silverlight-debugger-cannot-be-launched/31615770#31615770 which started when I updated the app. If it is only the debug issue then for me it was enough to create a new solution and import the old project. At least if it is the same error :)

Answer (score 1):

The only time I have seen this error was when the app is already installed on device\Emulator, I had to remove the app , then hit F5 to work.

Comment: Thanks RashmiA, i've already remove the app from the emulator but it still not work.